# R reorder ggplot x axis to end with zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a script

```
combined_co2%>%
  rename(carbon_dioxide_ppmv=co2)%>%
  ggplot(mapping =aes(x = yrBP, y = carbon_dioxide_ppmv))+

  geom_line()->g_line
  g_line+
  annotate( geom ="curve",
            x  = 2e+05,
            y  = 400,
            xend = 280,
            yend  = 400,
            curvature = 0.3,
             arrow = arrow(length=unit(1.5, "mm")),
             alpha = 0.8, 
              colour = "#00BFC4") ->g_curve
             g_curve+
            annotate(
              geom = "text",
              x = 3e+05,
              y = 400,
              label = "2021 average:400 ppmv",
              hjust = 0.1, vjust = -0.1,
              lineheight = 0.8, 
              colour= "#00BFC4"
            )
```

This script produces the below chart

[image]

Now I am trying to flip the x-axis to get the below chart instead:

[image]

How can I achieve this please? I have tried multiple orderings and sorting but to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any data it's possible to give only a generic solution, you can try this:

```
library(ggplot2) 
set.seed(123)
# some fake data
df <- data.frame(x = 1900:2000, y =rnorm(101) )
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()  + scale_x_reverse()
```

[image]

Without the `scale_x_reverse()`:

[image]